# Some html tags are missing when i write to a file using python requests

Tags: python-3.x, forms, python-requests

I am trying to login to a website using requests.The website requies token for its login.
so decided to parse the html and write it to a file.txt But the file.txt is missing the token tag.

HTML code:

```
    <form id="pw_form" class="exception_password" action="/409514769/password" method="post" data-xsrf-protection="enabled">
                <input type="password" id="password" class="exception_password-input iris_input" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off" data-validators="required">
                <input type="hidden" name="is_review" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="is_file_transfer" value="">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="iris_btn iris_btn--primary">
                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="4dc82c1a780e11667650f856da9b1d9fd31b176b.e7mu8nmqrb.1587446534"></form>
```

PYTHON code:

```
from requests import Session
with Session() as s:
    site = s.get("https://vimeo.com/409")
    with open('page.txt','w') as out:
        out.write(site.text)
```

This is what the file writes:

```
<form id="pw_form" class="exception_password" action="/409514769/password" method="post">
                <input type="password" id="password" class="exception_password-input iris_input" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" class="password iris_form_text" autocomplete="off" data-validators="required">
                <input type="hidden" name="is_review" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="is_file_transfer" value="">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="iris_btn iris_btn--primary">

                            </form>
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website don't allow request from bot.
One possible solution to this problem is to add headers while making the request.

Comment: This is the solution, But forgot to update this question.